# get values of dynamic checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am dynamically creating checkboxes in VB.Net and an .aspx page, based on values in my db.  I'm placing them in a two column table for ease of alignment.  this part works fine.

```
 Private Async Function InitForEditAsync() As Task

    Dim docList = Await GetLoanApplicationConfigurationDocs()
    Dim row = New HtmlTableRow()
    Dim cell = New HtmlTableCell()
    Dim i = 0

    For Each doc In docList

        Dim chkBox = New HtmlInputCheckBox()
        Dim lbl = New Label()

        Dim remainder = i Mod 2

        chkBox.ID = "chkDocId" + doc.Id.ToString
        lbl.Text = doc.DisplayName
        cell.Controls.Add(chkBox)
        cell.Controls.Add(lbl)

        row.Cells.Add(cell)
        cell = New HtmlTableCell()

        If remainder <> 0 OrElse i = docList.Count() - 1 Then
            tblEdit.Rows.Add(row)
            row = New HtmlTableRow()

        End If

        i += 1
    Next
End Function
```

Now I need to retrieve the values without knowing the id's but am not having any luck.  I tried this:

```
        For Each chkBox As HtmlInputCheckBox In pnlEdit.Controls.OfType(Of HtmlInputCheckBox)
```

but the checkboxes are not returned in the list of controls.  The table is, but there are no rows in the table object when I explored it in the control collection and when I tried this:

```
For Each row As HtmlTableRow In tblEdit.Rows.OfType(Of HtmlTableRow)
```

If it will help, here is a Snip of the UI and the HTML that is created:
[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some ideas I got from another site, I'm going to rewrite this using the asp:CheckBoxList. apparently it binds like a datagrid and you can enumerate through it. Seems like what i need.

UPDATE: Everything I posted to start was resolved with five lines of code!  "cblDocList is my asp CheckboxList and docList is my ienumerable of objects.

```
    cblDocList.RepeatColumns = 2
    cblDocList.DataSource = docList
    cblDocList.DataTextField = "DisplayName"
    cblDocList.DataValueField = "Id"
    cblDocList.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s something you can do through a loop for each row and each cell or using Linq to have only cells that have controls of type HtmlInputCheckBox inside.
I have simplified your code to be able run that here also shows you an example to achieve your task. Obviously you must change following your exigences .
Hope I well understood :)

```
    Dim tblEdit As New HtmlTable

    For k As Integer = 0 To 10

        Dim cell = New HtmlTableCell()
        Dim row = New HtmlTableRow()
        Dim chkBox = New HtmlInputCheckBox()

        Dim lbl = New Label()
        Dim remainder = k Mod 2

        chkBox.ID = "chkDocId_" + k.ToString
        chkBox.Checked = remainder = 0
        lbl.Text = "Text indicator of CheckBox nr:" + k.ToString

        cell.Controls.Add(chkBox)
        cell.Controls.Add(lbl)

        row.Cells.Add(cell)

        cell = New HtmlTableCell()
        tblEdit.Rows.Add(row)

    Next

    Dim checkBoxes As IEnumerable(Of HtmlInputCheckBox) =
        (From mRow In tblEdit.Rows).Select(Function(mr)
                                               Dim cb = (From cc In CType(mr, HtmlTableRow).Cells
                                                         Where CType(cc, HtmlTableCell).Controls.OfType(Of HtmlInputCheckBox).Count > 0
                                                         Select CType(cc, HtmlTableCell).Controls.OfType(Of HtmlInputCheckBox)()(0)).FirstOrDefault

                                               Return CType(cb, HtmlInputCheckBox)
                                           End Function).ToList


    For Each checkBox In checkBoxes
        Debug.WriteLine("CheckBox ID: {0}  Checked: {1} ", checkBox.ID, checkBox.Checked)
    Next
```